# SpringBoot project that includes Apache MetaModel fails to start with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback

Tags: java

I'm building a SpringBoot-based project that will include Apache MetaModel. SpringBoot is version 1.5.8.

Starting up a SpringBoot app works fine, and I can get to published pages. At the moment, the project is pretty much a skeleton app with only very basic features.

However, as soon as I add:

```
compile 'org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-full:5.0.0'
```

to my Gradle dependencies, startup fails with the notorious NoClassDefFound exception for FutureFallback. No other code added, and no configuration added or modified: reproducing the problem simply requires including the compile declaration to cause the startup failure.

I've tried including various versions of Guava and of MetaModel itself, as recommended by other answers, but none of them change the startup failure.

My gradle.build is currently thus:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'  

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':commons')
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-full:5.0.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.8-dmr'
    compile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.3.4.jre8-preview'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11'
    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.3.1'
//    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.4-jre'    
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'    
    testCompile (
        'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1',
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'
    )
    testRuntime(
        'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.1',
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'
    )

}
```

Evidence of tinkering with Guava versions is evident. Versions 16, 19, 20 and 23.4-jre have been tried.

Ideas for other avenues of repair greatly appreciated.

Comment: I managed to work around it by excluding Cassandra from the build.

`    compile ('org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-full:5.0.0') {`
 `     exclude group: 'org.apache.metamodel', module: 'MetaModel-cassandra'`
`    }`

Comment: Even better solution: leave the module in the build classpath, so it can be used later if desired, and exclude the SpringBoot autoconfiguration in the main application:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {CassandraAutoConfiguration.class})`